# firebase - if statement not executed after query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have integrated firebase in a vue app. I have a navbar that can show some user informations like name and status, and I need to query firebase realtime database after the login to set the needed informations inside my store that will manage application state.

I'm using this code when the navbar component is mounted but the `if()` statement will be not executed. The strange thing is that I'm able to log each user during the loop. Is there something wrong or another solution to achive this?

```js
        onValue(query(ref(db, 'Users'), orderByKey('uid')), users => {
            users.forEach( (user) => {
                let userData = user.val()
                // the console will log each user correctly
                console.log(userData)

                if( userData.uid == store.currentUser.uid ) {
                    console.log('called')
                    console.log(userData)
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: Can you also log `store.currentUser.uid`?

Comment: @AndresGardiol yes, the value is set after the user login and the navbar is only loaded for logged in users

Comment: Ok, so maybe you can log the if expression and see if it's `true`, maybe `userData.uid` is undefined

Comment: @AndresGardiol seems started wirking again. Not sure why the function was not executed.